# CodeIgniter : Redirect after generation of PDF file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, pdf

i am creating a PDF using TCPDF library. User form is submitted using ajax and a pdf is generated to the specified folder.

```
$filename= "$name.pdf"; 
$filelocation = $location 

$fileNL = $filelocation."\\".$filename;  
$this->pdf->Output($fileNL, 'F');
```

Now above code is in my view that is receiving data from controller sent through ajax and  is responsible for generating the PDF . PDF is generated but i am not able to redirect the page after generation and stay on the same form page.

I tried JS / Jquery redirects as well but did not work since i found PHP headers can't be sent anymore , Can someone advise me any solution for this problem ,

I need to redirect to success page after generation of the PDF

Comment: Why don't you do this "$this->pdf->Output($fileNL, 'F');" in the controller?

Comment: pdf generation code is there in the view file as provided by TCPDF library

Comment: Since you are saving the generated PDF in the server, the best place to put this code is in the Controller it self. That is the easiest way to avoid the problem you are having now. Once PHP headers are sent, you cant print anything else.

Comment: okay, so its a long messy html code seen here : https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/ should i have all this in the same controller ? would it be standard practice,  and if there is no other sol i wont mind doing that of course

Comment: If the form is sent using AJAX, why not redirect the user with `location = "some/url";` in the AJAX success callback? Putting a redirect header in the reply to an AJAX request won't do anything anyway.

Comment: okay can try on that , if it works that would be good solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to add status in Output function:

```
$filename= "$name.pdf"; 
$filelocation = $location 
$success_location = '/generated_success.php'; //redirect path after success
$failed_location = '/generated_failed.php';   //redirect path after failed

$fileNL = $filelocation."\\".$filename;  
$status = $this->pdf->Output($fileNL, 'F');
if($status==true){
    redirect($success_location);
}else{
    redirect($failed_location);
}
```